# IE8 Sharepoint - JS Resources " is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, xml, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

I have some JS Resources in a "JSResources.resx.scriptx" file. In that file I have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/resxscriptx" javascriptClassName="AAA.BBB.Res">
```

If I open a page that has something like this: 
    if (record.properties['Weight'].localizedValue == AAA.BBB.Res.NaN)

(Where NaN is a Token in that XML, and has resorces in the JSResources.AA-BB.resx files)

in any modern browser it works perfect, but if I open it on IE8, it will generate an JS error:   ***'AAA.BBB.Res' is null or not an object.***

If you have any ideeas please tell me...

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on IE8 was from another js file thas was overrideing the AAA js namespace, because it had a "var AAA;" at the start of the file.